# All permissions Android system

Tags: android, permissions, system

I came across an app capability in the Android System permissions that when tapped on gives no explanation only two letters "ok" the permission is: android.permission.UPDATE_PACKAGES_WITHOUT_USER_ACTION spelt out exactly this way. What does this mean?

I tapped on the permission and got a blank screen with only "ok" being shown. No explanation for the permission parameters.